# While loop not working in Android

Tags: android, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make a while loop that will make a number count up. However, when the app runs, it just crashes. Here's the code I used:

```
Thread Timer = new Thread(){
 public void run(){
     try{
         int logoTimer = 0;
         while(logoTimer != 5000){
             sleep(100);
             logoTimer = logoTimer + 1; 
             button.setText(logoTimer);
         }
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     finally{
         finish(); 
     }
 }
};
Timer.start();
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to add something in the .xml file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're getting a crash you should include the stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 3):

it does crash for two reasons

1. you are touching the UI from a thread that is not the UI Thread
2. you are calling `setText(int)`, which looks up for a string inside `string.xml`. If it does not exits, the `ResourceNotFoundException` will be thrown.

Edit: as G.T. pointed out you can use `button.setText(logoTimer+"")`; to avoid the exception at point 2

Comment: Just to complete your answer, the second point can be easily solved by casting the `int` to `String` like this: `button.setText(logoTimer+"");`

Comment: when I use button.setText(logoTimer+"");, it works for a second or two and then crashes (before it crashes, it updates the button).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the setText for the button on the UI thread!

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         button.setText(logoTimer);
    }
});
```